# Safest way of shrinking /Home, adding partiton, and where to mount?

Tags: partitioning, mount

There are clear directions on the web for changing partitions in Ubuntu using Gparted and live USB. I want to shrink the /Home partition, and add another beside it. But I am not sure what type of partiton to create if it's just for storing docs etc -'Logical, primary, EXT 4, etc. I also don't know what the mount point should be. 
/Home hasn't been used much yet, as this is fairly new install (just a couple of days) on USB to dual boot into a Windows machine. Because I didn't know the answers to the above questions, I didn't create the other partition at the time of install.
Thanks.

Comment: You mount home at /home , no /Home (note cap) . There is no method safer than any other but to make a back up first.

Comment: If you make the new partition FAT32 or NTFS it will be visible when plugged into a Windows 10 machine, for older versions of Windows, it must also be the first partition. If you don't care about Windows many people prefer ext 2 as it is non journaling and may help preserve drive life.

Comment: The safest way is to make three backups first.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron both fat and ntfs are horrible for /home. fat will not work at all.

Comment: Thanks:-) I think parts of my question weren't clear. Once I have shrunk the /home partition, where would the most usual mount point be for the new one I will create? What difference does it make whether it's a logical or primary partition?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/999582/edit) your question and make it clear. It is not clear what partition scheme you have now. Please take a screenshot of gparted and upload it in https://imgur.com/. Then add a link to the image in your question. This will help us understand how many primary partitions you have and if `/home` is in a separate partition or not. If `/home` is not in a separate partition, then there are tutorials for how to move it to a separate partition. May be that's what you want.

Comment: As I said earlier, you mount a separate home partition at /home . Linux is case sensitive so /home is not the same as /Home . I am not sure what part of that advice you do not get. https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/

Comment: Hi,I am not wanting to change mount point of /home. I am wanting to shrink /home, and create a new partition in the empty space left.                  Yes, when I boot into Linux next, will take screenshot of Gparted. I wonder if can paste pic in here rather than opening an account on an image sharing site.

Comment: @Panther No, no, no, I would not suggest using FAT32 or NTFS for /home that does not work. The op just wants to "shrink the /Home partition, and add another beside it" If he wants a data partition on his USB, why not one that both Linux and Windows can use, at least if he might ever want to transfer data to/from a Windows machine.

Comment: @jayuu If I recall correctly the mount point for a FAT32 or NTFS partition is "windows", when partitioning with "something else".

Comment: @jayuu Oops, correction, mount point for NTFS/FAT32 partition in a Ubuntu install is "/windows".

Comment: You may not have enough reputation here yet to directly upload the screenshot to this site. Uploading the image in imgur does not require opening an account. Once you post the link to your image in imgur in the [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/999582/edit) question, someone with more reputation can review the image and add it to the question.

Comment: Why not just post a link to the screenshot?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help:-) In the meantime the nature of my question changed, and someone popped up who could sort me out. So am signing off this thread.